# Getting two errors, keyerror and typeerror after script is left to run for a while

Tags: python, debugging, typeerror, keyerror

After running this bit of code in an endless while True loop, it randomly crashes and throws these two errors:

`TypeError: string indices must be integers`

`Keyerror: l (this is the letter "L", FWIW)`

The problem here is that works and then just crashes. Sometimes it will crash after the first iteration of the while True loop, other times it can run for as long as 20 minutes before crashing.

This is the bit of code. It is pulling OHLC price data from Bitmex. What it does is takes the last 30, 1 minute candles and then finds the lowest "low" price from all 30.
If you try it by importing bitmex, json and requests, it should work no problem for every manual try. When it runs on a loop, it will randomly crash. Any ideas?

```
def lowest_price():
    response = requests.get("https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/trade/bucketed?binSize=1m&partial=false&symbol=XBTUSD&count=30&reverse=true").json()
    minimum = min([l['low'] for l in response])
    return(minimum)
```

Comment: You are receiving a bad response from the server. Check the response code and handle all other errors with `try` / `except`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that sometimes, you get results from the server which your script cannot parse.

The `TypeError` occurs when your JSON result is decoded to a `list` of strings; say, `["Invalid input"]`. Clearly `"Invalid input"['low']` makes no sense, since you can't index strings with string keys.

On the other hand, the `KeyError` happens when you get a JSON object that represents a `list` of `dicts`, *at least one of which does not contain the `'low'` key.

To solve this, you can wrap your parsing logic in a `try-except` block that looks for the desired data and returns something like `None` if it can't be found. You could also inspect the result code of the `get` call.